# How to find out if a sub is assigned to any userform inputbox

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I inherited a file from a co-worker that is no longer with the company.
In the file are about two dozen of Sub's, with a lot of duplications and redundancy's. There are about a dozen of userform inputboxes in the excel file.

Is there an easy way to check if a certain sub is linked to an inputbox?

I know I can check for each inputbox which Sub is linked to it, but I want to check for it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoint at every sub. Having set that, play with inputbox in any way you can imagine. If this triggers any sub, you will see that, because code will stop at the breakpoint.

This is most straightforward approach I can think of.

Comment: This would be no faster then checking for each inputbox what Sub is assigned.